# Checkstyle saying "Conditional logic can be removed"?

Tags: java, checkstyle

This is the part that checkstyle doesn't like, specifically the "if (eggs >= 3)" line. How can I change this to make it pass for checkstyle?

```
if (flour >= 1) 
    {
        if (sugar >= 2) 
        {
            if (eggs >= 3) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: A shorter expression should do better:`return flour >= 1 && sugar >= 2 && eggs >=3;`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean foo(int flour, int sugar, int eggs) {
    return flour >=1 && sugar >= 2 && eggs >=3;
}
```